# JavaScript timing in Puppeteer

Tags: java, pdf, mathjax

I'm trying to convert an HTML page to PDF using Puppeteer. The page in question uses Mathjax to render formulas. It appears that Puppeteer is not letting the page scripts complete before rendering.
Is there a semaphore to use to wait for re-render before writing to PDF?

I get good results when using an online convert tool https://html2pdf.com/
[image: Correctly rendered]

However, I get incomplete results when using Puppeteer.
[image: Incorrectly rendered]

Comment: The base HTML

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsDqSHL4-Yguk7VkMkaOMi7GENjebg

Comment: That's what I was looking for, a timer or a semaphore to tell it when it's finished re-rendering by Mathjax. Thanks.

Comment: Here's the corrected code adding navigation options
        var navigation = new NavigationOptions
            {   Timeout = 0,
                WaitUntil = new[] {WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle0 }
            };
        await page.GoToAsync("https://localhost:44392/Calculation.html", navigation);